# Improve OGR SQL query for polygon intersection using WKT geometry

Tags: gdal, polygon, sql, ogr, intersection

I want calculate the intersected area between a shapefile and WKT geometry.

- My target big layer: `a.shp`
- My query small layer: `'POLYGON((1150046 1264030, 1160100 1263793, 1160079 1260606, 1150218 1260822, 1150046 1264030))'`

I have the following `ogrinfo` expression that is actually working:

```
ogrinfo a.shp -dialect sqlite  -sql "SELECT id, sum(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(
GEOMETRY, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1150046 1264030, 1160100 1263793, 1160079 1260606, 1150218 1260822, 1150046 1264030))')))) as m2 FROM a WHERE ST_Intersects(GEOMETRY, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1150046 1264030, 1160100 1263793, 1160079 1260606, 1150218 1260822, 1150046 1264030))'))"
```

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT col1, sum(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(
GEOMETRY, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(( ... ))')))) as col2 
FROM a 
WHERE ST_Intersects(GEOMETRY, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(( ... ))'))"
```

Could this SQL query be written better to get faster results?

Comment: GeoPackage does not use the spatial index automatically like PostGIS but you must add a subquery. Find the details about the syntax from https://erouault.blogspot.com/2017/03/dealing-with-huge-vector-geopackage.html.